# Why do I get an H2 error when deploying my Grails WAR to Tomcat

Tags: mysql, maven, tomcat, grails, h2

I'm trying to deploy my Grails 2.2.4 application to Tomcat 6.5. The application has two environments configured in DataSource.groovy.

Whether I build my application using 'mvn clean package' or thru the 'grails war' I get an error about a particular table not existing. When I launch the application thru 'groovy run-app' I have no problems connection to the same database. Any idea of what's wrong with my config?

**Tomcat Deployment Error**

```
Nov 12, 2013 4:16:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [select count(*) as y0_ from monkey_classification this_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [select count(*) as y0_ from monkey_classification this_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
        at BootStrap$_closure4.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:24)
        at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "MONKEY_CLASSIFICATION" not found; SQL statement:
select count(*) as y0_ from monkey_classification this_ [42102-164]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4753)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1080)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1686)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1793)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1680)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1523)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1511)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:405)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:217)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:415)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:364)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1121)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:71)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:267)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)
        ... 10 more
Nov 12, 2013 4:16:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Nov 12, 2013 4:16:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/application-monkey-tool-0.1] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 12, 2013 4:16:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Nov 12, 2013 4:16:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/application-monkey-tool-0.1] registered the JDBC driver [org.h2.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Nov 12, 2013 4:16:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/application-monkey-tool-0.1] appears to have started a thread named [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@1b4a4fd2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

**DataSource.groovy:**

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username = "amt"
            password = "password"
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:mysql://10.x.x.x:3306/amt"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
            username = "sa"
            password = ""
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dataSource {
                driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                username = "amt"
                password = "password"
                dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
                url = "jdbc:mysql://10.x.x.x:3306/amt"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**maven build output**

```
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:2.2.4:maven-grails-app-war (default-maven-grails-app-war) @ application-monkey-tool ---

|Loading Grails 2.2.4
|Configuring classpath
|Running pre-compiled script
.
|Environment set to prod
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
..
|Compiling 1 source files
..............
|Compiling 21 GSP files for package [applicationMonkeytOol]
..
|Compiling 8 GSP files for package [jodaTime]
.
|Compiling 7 GSP files for package [easygrid]
.
|Compiling 4 GSP files for package [databaseMigration]
..
|Building WAR file
..............................................................
|Done creating WAR target\application-monkey-tool-0.1.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 52.528s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 12 11:12:57 EST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/244M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have two dataSource defined in your dsl, should be like this:

```
production {
        dataSource {
                driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                username = "amt"
                password = "password"
                dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
                url = "jdbc:mysql://10.x.x.x:3306/amt"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Augh! Yes, that fixed the problem. Thank you.

I didn't notice any messages from Grails complaining about this, or that it was falling back to the default of H2. Is there a place that I should look for this, or an additional step to take that might help give hints for this problem in the future?

Comment: DSL are sometimes tricky as it might just ignore the things that don't understand.  You said it works in dev not in prod, so I just looked at the difference between those two.